# Android - When my phone is locked, my app is not working

Tags: android

I have a application. When i press volume down button, counter is increasing. but i want to do when my device is lock.

When i pressed power button, counter is not working.

```
if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        switch (event.getKeyCode()) 
        {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:

            counter=counter+1;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You need a background service for this. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I don't believe that's possible with an activity. When locked, your activity is suspended and will not receive any events. Look into the possibility of a service as Osiriz suggests.

Comment: @Osiriz Is it possible for a service to capture a volume down key press in a stock system? I'm unaware of that.

Comment: There is a Broadcast for it ( `IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION");` ). I would catch this event in a service and handle it.

Answer (score 1):

MyAs mentioned in the comments of your question, you can use service.

Alternatively, I guess it can be done in Activity with the use of wakelock too. Acquire a partial wakelock in your activity. This way, the CPU wont go to sleep and your activity keeps running.

For acquiring wakelock:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Wakelock");
wl.acquire();
```

For releasing wakelock:

```
  wl.release();
```

You can acquire wakelock when your activity is created and release the wakelock when the activity is destroyed.

Comment: Permission is also needed in the manifest: < uses-permission android:name =" android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/ >  Mehmetk: be careful when using wakelocks since they can have a big impact on battery life.

Comment: Ohh yes, forgot to add about permission. And yes, as @NigelK mentioned, wakelocks have impact on battery life.